# django-wysiwyg-redactor doesn't work in inlines

Tags: django, inline-formset, django-wysiwyg

So I am using django-wysiwyg-redactor==0.4.9 and Django==1.9.
The issue described [here](https://github.com/douglasmiranda/django-wysiwyg-redactor/issues/90).

I tried a trick in comments, but that didn't help.
Also in browser's console I run this code directly to needed textarea:

```
$('#id_outboundprogram_set-2-text').trigger('redactor:init');
```

But anyway there are no redactor on it.
Textarea element looks like this before and after running above code:

```
<textarea class=" redactor-box" cols="40" data-redactor-options="{"lang": "en", "fileUpload": "/en/redactor/upload/file/", "imageUpload": "/en/redactor/upload/image/", "plugins": ["table", "video"]} id="id_outboundprogram_set-2-text" name="outboundprogram_set-2-text" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Strange thing is that this code, that I found in jquery.redactor.init.js from package files is not working:

```
// Initialize Redactor on admin's dynamically-added inline
// formsets.
//
// Credit to the approach taken in django-selectable:
// https://github.com/mlavin/django-selectable
$(document).on('click', '.add-row', function () {
    $(this).parents('.inline-related')
           .find('tr.form-row:not(.empty-form)').last()
           .find('textarea.redactor-box')
           .trigger('redactor:init');
});
```

Any ideas?

**UPD:**

Well, I still don't know why it happpens, but I solved this problem by including `redactor.js` file from package files and adding a little changes to above script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/admin/redactor.js' %}"></script>    
var program_tab = $('#outboundprogram_set-group');  // this is just because I have several inlines
    program_tab.children('.add-row').on('click', function(){
        program_tab.children('.inline-related:not(.empty-form)')
                            .last()
                            .find('textarea.redactor-box')
                            .redactor();
    });
```

**UPD 2:**

Using this soution there is no plugins and image/file handlers. So I researched a little and found [this](http://paltman.com/how-to-setup-upload-handler-for-redactor/) article.

But image and file handling already implemented in django-wysiwyg-redactor, so I need just to use `RedactorUploadView()`. Urls can be found in urls.py file from sources. So here is the code:

```
var program_tab = $('#outboundprogram_set-group');
program_tab.children('.add-row').on('click', function(){
    program_tab.children('.inline-related:not(.empty-form)')
                        .last()
                        .find('textarea.redactor-box')
                        .redactor({
                            imageUpload: "{% url 'redactor_upload_image' 'tours/out/programs/img/' %}",
                            fileUpload: "{% url 'redactor_upload_file' 'tours/out/programs/files/' %}",
                            plugins: ['table', 'video', 'fullscreen', 'image']
                        });
});
```